# Need to set up default permission for newly creating files and directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

i use acl for setup the default permission for newly created files and directories under `/var/www/html/myproject/`. but the default permisson is not reflecting to the new files and directory.

i used this commands to setup

```
setfacl -R -m u:username:rwx /var/www/html/**
setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwx /var/www/html/**
setfacl -R -m o::rx /var/www/html/***/

getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/html/***/
# owner: username
# group: www-data
# flags: ss-
user::rwx
user:username:rwx
group::rwx
group:www-data:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Please help me to fix this

my issue

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 user www-data    0 Oct  8 06:29 hari.html
```

Comment: What does `getfacl` return for `hari.html`?

Comment: I don't see any default ACLs there? I.e. `setfacl -d`, or ACL entries starting with `default:`.

Comment: @roaima the same one it's not reflecting the newly created files or folders

Comment: The same as what? Please would you either add the result to your question or clarify _also in your question_ what the ACL is on your example file

Comment: @roaima   I setup -ed chmod -R 755 to my /var/www/myproject directory, but every time we update code or created a new file inside the directory its not reflecting to this  775 permission. so i need to set up default permission for the file which are created newly. this is my issue, so please help me with this roaima

Comment: Please update your question with the information. It doesn't belong in comments